# is this function a closure in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
    function f1(){
        var n=999;
        function f2(){
            alert(n); // 999
        }
    }
```

is the function `f2()` a closure? if not? why?

but in this post. [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)
why it says:

```
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;
  function bar(y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp));
  }
  bar(10);
}
foo(2)
```

**That is not a closure.A closure is when you return the inner function. The inner function will close-over the variables of foo before leaving.** why?

but i don't know what's the difference between the example i made and another i cited, one is not a closure.but one is. i think the two example is the same.

Comment: What prompted this question? What answer were you expecting? More context will lead to better answers...

Comment: Doesn't f1 need to be stored in a variable, or f2 need to be returned and that stored in a variable in order for it to truly be a closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `f2` is a closure, since it accesses a variable (`n`) from an outer scope. (OK, it's not really a closure -- see update below).

`n` was declared inside `f1`, not `f2`; this makes it belong to `f1`'s scope. So when you create the function `f2` which references `n`, it is a closure by definition, since it uses someone else's variable.

**UPDATE**

Alright, if I understand the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) you've linked to correctly, it says that `f2` is *not* a closure because it is merely accessing a variable within its scope (just like an `if` statement, which gets its own scope within the braces<sup>*</sup>, can use variables from the outer scope without needing a closure).

<sup>* **Update:** Turns out that only functions get their own scope in Javascript, not any old blocks. But my point still stands...</sup>

However, `f2` *would become* a closure if it left `f1`'s scope (e.g. by being returned); in that case, it would still have access to `f1`'s variable `n`, even though `f1`'s original scope would no longer exist (it's exited when control leaves the function). `f2` would have "closed over" `f1`'s variables, thus artificially extending the lifespan of `f1`'s scope.

Personally, I would still call `f2` a closure, even if it never leaves `f1`. If a function can *become* a closure simply by being used outside of its declaring scope, and its behaviour inside that scope is no different whether it's technically a closure or not, then I see no point in making a distinction. I would even go so far as to say that it's an implementation detail whether `f2` is a closure or not, if it never leaves `f1`'s scope.

On the other hand, ignoring that distinction would mean that any function that uses a global variable would be called a "closure", since it accesses a variable from an outer scope. So the fact that it becomes a closure only when it leaves the scope(s) that the variables it is using are defined in *is* a worthwhile (albeit subtle) distinction.

I guess the clearest answer I can give is that **it's not a closure *yet***.

Comment: i have updated my queston. there is an example like f2 function. but it says it's not a closure. thank you.

Comment: i am sorry, i am still really understand it well :)

Comment: @runeveryday: Picture the inside of an `if` block. Inside that block, you can declare variables that are visible only within that block (this is a scope). But you can read and modify variables that were declared within the function that encloses the `if` (one of the `if`'s outer scopes). That `if` is just like your `f2` function right up to that point. There is no closure. But if you return the `f2` function, or otherwise expose it outside of `f1` (something that cannot be done to `if`s since they are not objects), then `f2` can still access `n`, even though it was from `f1`! That's a closure.

Comment: @runeveryday: In other words, when I first said that `f2` was a closure, I was wrong (at least technically). It is not a closure *until it leaves `f1`'s scope*. Only *then* is it a closure. In your example (and the one you linked to), the inner function never leaves the outer function's scope. So even though it uses variables from the outer function, it doesn't need to be a closure in order to do so (just like an `if`), *unless it leaves that outer function* -- in which case it turns into a closure around the variables that it references from the outer function/scope(s). Better? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is a closure, because it depends on the values of variables in an intermediate (i.e. not local or global) scope, and if the variable changes then so will the operation of the closure. That the value is always the same is incidental.

You may however want to return the closure to the caller of `f1()` so that it can be used elsewhere.